# Filling an image using magick package

Tags: r, imagemagick

This image should be filled using smaller images:

[image]

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(imager)


im <- load.image("white_rectangle.jpg") 
px <- im > 0.4 #Select pixels of the circle (i.e., those with high luminance)
coord <- where(px)

boundaries <- imager::boundary(px)
boundaries.xy <- where(boundaries)

x_coord <- boundaries.xy$x
y_coord <- boundaries.xy$y
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)

p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps1 = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
plot(sps1)
```

I am trying to use magick package in order to fill the previous image.

One of the ideas about to solve it, was trying to fill it with a cube of images like a matrix of 3x3.

```
bigdata <- 
image_read('https://jeroen.github.io/images/bigdata.jpg')
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
logo <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png")
img <- c(bigdata, logo, frink)
img <- image_scale(img, "300x300")
image_info(img)

new_i <- image_append(image_scale(img, "x200"))
```

My current code returns a vector of 3, I don't understand how to create a matrix of 3 x 3 images:

```
  image_append(new_i,new_i,new_i stack = TRUE)
```

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by "fill an image" and how does that relate to a cube of 3x3? Can you explain in more detail or show a diagram of what you are trying to achieve? What is the 3x3 matrix to represent? It looks to me like you are simply appending 3 images side-by-side.

Comment: Well, I am wondering how to fill a geometric figure with images. So, I am thinking in create the form appending images. For example if I want to create a rhombus, that could be [1 image, 3 images, 5 images, 3 images, 1 image].

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. Is this a 3D figure or a 2D figure?  What do you mean by "fill"?  Please provide a diagram or example image. You can put images on the faces of 3D objects and show one view of the object. A cube is the simplest. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Dbox/index.php. Is that what you are trying to do? That is much more complex that just appending images as you seem to be doing above.

Comment: I have already added the image to be filled and the code that I am using to obtain the images. Everything in 2D. In this moment I don't know how to fill the big image with the small images. All the small images have the same dimensions.

Comment: You have not said how big your 3 input images are, nor how you want to fill the 3 images into the one - horizontally, vertically, tiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how big your input images are, nor how you want them filled. But if you want them to just be appended side-by-side, then in Imagemagick command line, I would do:

Input (repeated 3 times):

[image]

Your image to be filled is 630x380 after subtracting the border. I get that by

```
convert img.jpg -fuzz 15% -format "%@" info:
630x380+10+10
```

So doing the appending and inserting into your image:

```
convert img.jpg \( monet2.jpg monet2.jpg monet2.jpg +append -resize 630x380^ -gravity center -extent 630x380 \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Is this what you are trying to do?

If you want a 3x3 grid of images, then adjust (resize and/or crop) the 3 images so that they are 1/3 of your background image in each dimensions The append 3 horizontally. The duplicated that 2 more times and append that set of 3 vertically. Then insert into your backgound image.

```
convert img.jpg \( \( monet2.jpg monet2.jpg monet2.jpg -resize 210x127^ -gravity center -extent 210x127 +append \) -duplicate 2 -append \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result1.jpg
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Another approach is to just tile out the image.

```
convert img.jpg -resize 210x127^ -gravity center -extent 210x127 -write mpr:img +delete -size 630x380 tile:mpr:img result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an Addition to my answer. Just tile out the image without having to append